# Share a Wifi connection through wifi on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, wireless-networking

I have a WiFi connection and I would like to share it through my WiFi card to computers. For some security reason, it seems that only one device can access the WiFi connection directly.

This is why I want to use the first mac computer as server.

Unfortunately, I don't have any Airport Express.

Comment: You cannot be connected to two wifis with only one interface. If you want the same machine to connect to your real wifi network *and* create or join an ad-hoc network with your other machines: This will not work.

Comment: @Daniel Beck is correct, to share over Wi-Fi you would need to be connected to your router using an ethernet cable and then set up a new wi-fi connection for sharing.

Comment: You can also share the WiFi connection via Firewire, probably not helpful in this situation but good to know.

Comment: @Daniel Beck and @Jay_Booney are not correct – otherwise, how could Connectify on Win7 share a Wifi connection [1,2]? @Arkan: Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you for Mac (was searching for one myself) but was compelled to correct the above comments.

[1] http://www.connectify.me/
[2] http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/create-a-wi-fi-access-point-using-connectify/2591

Comment: @orangechicken Connectify works by specifically requiring Windows 7 internals (no support for earlier Windows versions) and needing to support the network hardware to be able to create an AP, via the article you linked. As this question is specifically for OS X, my assessment still holds.

Comment: Would adding à second wireless adaptor true USB solve the problem ?

Comment: The point here is that if Windows can do it, it can't be a hardware limitation; so we would like to be able to do this on OSX as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. You can't take your connection from WiFi and share it to other devices via WiFi. You can think of it as plugging two ethernet cables into one port. It won't work.

You can, however, take your connection from ethernet and share it to devices using WiFi.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it could be possible with the bought of a device ?

Comment: @Arkan: Maybe a [Wireless Repeater](http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Linksys-Wireless-G-Range-Expander-WRE54G/dp/B00021XIJW) would do what you need?

Comment: You can't, provided you only have *one NIC*. If you would buy a USB Wireless Adapter for example, this should be doable.

Comment: Too bad on Apple only a connection can be made. On PC you can create a WiFi hotspot while connecting through WiFi. Some programs do that for you, for example: Connectify.

Answer (score 10):

Try this, it works for me. For example your wifi is en1.

```
sudo -s
ifconfig en1 x.x.x.1/24 alias
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
natd -interface en1
ipfw -f flush
ipfw add divert natd all from any to any via en1
ipfw add pass all from any to any
```

Other devices will connect to the same SSID but you need to use static IP in x.x.x.0/24 range.

Comment: DNS doesn't work through the 'OSX Router' but using Googles open DNS server (8.8.8.8) sorted that. Thanks

Comment: How do I un-do the above once I've issued the commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can't take WiFi connection and share it via your Airport, but if you for some reason cannot plug in an ethernet cable, and you have a second mac (brother's, sister's, friend's) then you can share Internet Connection from WiFi through bluetooth with one computer, and then share Internet Connection from bluetooth through your WiFi network. Again, **this only works if you have two macs.**

Comment: Can you explain how to do "You can share Internet Connection from WiFi through bluetooth with one computer, and then share Internet Connection from bluetooth through your WiFi network"